# How does following function notations work in terms of scalar multiplication?

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove the function is closed under multiplication (in a step to prove it's a subspace).

The problem is defined as:

> Show that the set of differentiable real-valued functions $f$ on the
> interval $(-4,4)$ such that $f'(-1)=3f(2)$ is a subspace of
> $\mathbb{R}^{(-4,4)}$

Now to prove it is closed under multiplication, we show, that multiplying by $k \in \mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align}
kf'(-1) &= k \, 3f(2) \\
(kf')(-1) &= 3 \, (kf)(2)
\end{align}

How should I think about the second line above in terms of scaling the function? Basically what is it expressing? An explanation would be nice.
Thanks.

Comment: $f'(-1)=3f(2)$ is not a function. Are you talking about the space of functions such that $f'(-1)=3f(2)$?

Comment: I am sorry, yes, you are correct. Yes, I am talking about the space of differentiable real-valued functions on the interval $(-4,4)$ to be precise. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
$$\frac{d}{dx}(cf(x)) = c\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$$

**I would do it likes this:**

Let $f\in \{\text{your space}\}$ and $k\in \mathbb{R}$.
To show that $kf\in \{\text{your space}\}$ we must show that
$$(kf)'(-1)=3(kf)(2) \tag{1}$$
(Notice here that the derivative sign is outside $kf$).

As is well known (and easy to show) $$\frac{d}{dx}(cf(x))=c\frac{d}{dx}f(x) \tag{$c\in \mathbb{R}$}$$
so $(kf)'(-1)=k(f'(-1))$ which means that $(1)$ becomes
$$k(f'(-1))=k(3f(2))$$
which holds for all non-zero $k$ since
$$f'(-1)=3f(2)$$
for all $f\in \{\text{your space}\}$ and $k=0$ is trivial.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense!

Comment: @Rio1210 No problem, happy to help!